# PHP syntax string join

Tags: php, mysql

```
    $a = '
        SELECT * FROM `'. $table .'` WHERE `chrDate` > "'. $lastDate .'" INTO OUTFILE "'. $file .'"
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ", " ENCLOSED BY \'"\' ESCAPED BY "\"
        LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
';
```

I dont know why i cant do this, I try to solve it several time but every time i give this error :(

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\n"' at line 2
```

**Echo $a **

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_SaleApa` WHERE `chrDate` > "2001/03/29" INTO OUTFILE "C:/xampp/htdocs/transfer/tempfile/tbl_SaleApa.sql"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ", " ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY "\"
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
```

Comment: can you show us what `echo $a;` outputs?

Comment: @S.Visser I tested nothing change :( \\n OR \n doesnt work in single quote.

Comment: Shouldn't `\n` also be escaped? `\\n` ?

Comment: try replacing `/` in file path with `\\ ` ?

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue Genius, that must have been the catch that we all missed. See the code below for the output. Grats, you didn't stop looking after the first error like the rest of us did. +1 Good show!

Comment: @goldenparrot It doesn't change any thing :(

Comment: @hamidreza66 Have another look at the code and output. You were encapsulating vars inside double quotes which was throwing out your code.

Comment: Is it ok to say `FIELDS` and not specify any like `(a,b,c)`?

Comment: @goldenparrot This is a table dump, not a normal query.

Comment: @Fluffeh I found the problem and post it, change `ESCAPED BY "\"` to `ESCAPED BY "\\\"`

Comment: @goldenparrot Just needed to change `ESCAPED BY "\"` to `ESCAPED BY "\\\"` Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

I have this:
Edit: You were also encapsulating variables inside double quotes which wasn't needed. See updated code.

```
<?php

$table='myTable';
$lastDate='myDate';
$file='myFile.ext';
$a = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE chrDate > '$lastDate' INTO OUTFILE '$file' 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ', ' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\\' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'"; 

echo $a;

?>
```

Which outputs this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE chrDate > 'myDate' INTO OUTFILE 'myFile.ext'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ', ' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = '
SELECT * FROM `'. $table .'` WHERE `chrDate` > "'. $lastDate .'" INTO OUTFILE "'. $file .'"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ", " ENCLOSED BY \'"\' ESCAPED BY "\\"
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $a = "SELECT * FROM " . $table . " WHERE chrDate > '" . $lastDate . "' INTO OUTFILE '" . $file . "' 
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ', ' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\\' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
```

Comment: Error change to `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line`

Answer (score 0):

My Problem Solved:

```
$a = '
SELECT * FROM `'. $table .'` WHERE `chrDate` > "'. $lastDate .'" INTO OUTFILE "'. $file .'"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ", " ENCLOSED BY \'"\' ESCAPED BY "\\\"
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
';
```

Change `ESCAPED BY "\"` to `ESCAPED BY "\\\"`